# Converting native JS Ajax snippet to JQuery alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am updating historic JS code from another author but having problems converting the below to the JQuery alternative:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', songurl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
if (this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('songdiv').innerHTML = '';
    song.src = (window.webkitURL ? webkitURL : URL).createObjectURL(this.response);
}
}
xhr.send();
```

This is more so to aide consistency, Chrome - developer tools is also suggesting the code to be re-factored.

Here is what I have started with (appreciate it's not much!), the issue I'm having is checking the status code and returning the response if the status code is 200.

```
$.ajax({
    url: songurl,
    method: 'GET'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax()`, or the shorthand [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), will do all that for you. There's a `success()` function that's only called on a successfull, 200-status request:

```
$.get( songurl, 
  function(data) {
    document.getElementById('songdiv').innerHTML = '';
    song.src = (window.webkitURL ? webkitURL : URL).createObjectURL(data);
  },
  'blob'
);
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Just being explicit about the unused `data` parameter. Unnecessary, though... I'll remove it.

Comment: Oh but usually better is to be explicit... :) I was wondering it because i'm not familiar with blob and it could have a specific reason

Comment: Appreciate the response, learnt something new...although sadly JQuery does not support blob by default!

Answer (score 2):

You want to attach [a function for success](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function).

```
$.ajax({
    url: songurl,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        //do stuff with response
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, was torn between which to accept but accepted the other due to extra commentary.

Comment: I'm surprised you accepted the other one since it uses a different function than what you originally went with.